# Taylor's Theorem expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to show that 
$f'(x) = (f(x-2h) - 4f(x-h)+3f(x)) / 2h +0(h^2)$
with Taylor series expansion of $f(x-h)$ and $f(x-2h)$. I got the expansions but I don't get the final answer correct, so I think I am missing something.

Comment: Probably just a simple calculation error. If you post your calculations, somebody may spot it.

Answer (score 0):

First notice by Taylor expansion that

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{{{h^2}}}{{2!}}f''(x) + o({h^3})$$

Next, replace $h$ by $-h$ and $-2h$ to obtain

$$\eqalign{
  & f(x - h) = f(x) - hf'(x) + {{{h^2}} \over {2!}}f''(x) + o({-h^3})  \cr 
  & f(x - 2h) = f(x) - 2hf'(x) + {{4{h^2}} \over {2!}}f''(x) + o({-8h^3}) \cr} $$

Now, try to eliminate the $f''(x)$ from the above equations

$$f(x - 2h) - 4f(x - h) =  - 3f(x) + 2hf'(x) + \left[ {o( - 8{h^3}) - 4o( - {h^3})} \right]$$

Next, solve for $f'(x)$ from the above to get

$$f'(x) = {1 \over {2h}}\left( {f(x - 2h) - 4f(x - h) + 3f(x)} \right) + \left[ {{{o( - 8{h^3}) - 4o( - {h^3})} \over { - 2h}}} \right]$$

Finally, by algebra of the *little o* you can show that

$${{o( - 8{h^3}) - 4o( - {h^3})} \over { - 2h}} = o({h^2})$$

and hence

$$f'(x) = {1 \over {2h}}\left( {f(x - 2h) - 4f(x - h) + 3f(x)} \right) + o({h^2})$$

Comment: @Vadims Gulkevics: Take a look at this. :)